# How to get the content of a div with class using BeautifulSoup?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

How to get the content of a div with class using web scraping?

I cannot fetch details of a single `div` with a class name.

```
import mechanize
import re
import logging

from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup
    br = mechanize.Browser()
    br.set_handle_equiv(False)
    url = "https://www.abcd.com"
    ua = 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:18.0) Gecko/20100101     Firefox/18.0 (compatible;)'
    br.addheaders =  [('User-Agent', ua), ('Accept', '*/*')]
    br.set_debug_http(True)
    logging.getLogger('mechanize').setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
    html = br.open(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html) 
    for i in soup.findAll('div', 'className'):
        print i
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use like this

```
soup.findAll('div', {'attribute-name': 'attribute-value'})
```

For example:

```
soup.findAll('div', {'class': 'class-name'})
```

Answer (score 1):

------top code-----

```
  html = br.open(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html) 
    for i in soup.findAll('div', {"class":"NAME_OF_CLASS"})
        print i
```

This should help you.